# The maximum number of girls you can accommodate in a row

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification

I was playing around with the following problem:

'What is the maximum number of girls in a group of boys and girls that can be seated in a row of $x$ seats so that no $n$ girls are sat next to each other'

This means in our row, we cannot have any occurrences of $\underbrace{\text{GGGG}\ldots}_{n \text{ times}}$

I came to the conclusion that in general, the answer is $x - \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{n}}\right \rfloor $ .

I first started with the case $n=4$ and realized that this came down to the maximum number of $GGGB$ blocks we can place in the row, of which this is $\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor$, and for each of these blocks we have $3$ girls, so that the number of girls in the row so far is $3(\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor)$. Now adding on the remaining girls we can fit on the extreme right, which is the remainder on division of $x$ by $4$, that is  $x - 4(\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor)$, the maximum number of girls is $x - 4(\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor) + 3(\left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor) = x - \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{4}}\right \rfloor$

Is my working correct? And secondly if possible I would like to know if this formula has any significance to graph theory.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT 1: The total number of boys and girls must sum to $x$

Comment: Are you supposing girls to be indistinct if not so there should ne a factor of ${m\choose n}$ where m are total girls and n is asper your question

Comment: Could you explain how girls being distinct or indistinct is relevant to the question?

Comment: Now thats common sense distinct girls imply distint combinationa while if same girls then we can choose only in $1$ way

Comment: It would be common sense if the question I posed asked about combinations at all. No reference to the number of combinations of anything was made. I was asking what the maximum number of girls I can fit in a row of maximum capacity $x$ so that no $n$ girls are next to each other is. So it doesn't matter if the girls are indexed or not.

Comment: Then it has to be mentioned or we need to make$2$ cases

Comment: The question is unambiguous as it is. How does 'What is the maximum number of girls in a group of boys and girls that can be seated in a row of $x$ seats so that no $n$ girls are sat next to each other' provoke the thought of combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graph theory applications, this question is equivalent to:

Out of all red-blue vertex colorings of $P_n$, what is the largest possible number of vertices colored red such that the graph contains no red $P_k$ $(k<n)$?

Which is kind of like a Ramsey-type problem. On its own, I would say this is too easy to be interesting, but asking a similar question with other common classes of graphs may yield interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $M$ the maximum number of girls you can fit. 
What you have is a construction that shows the answer is $M \geq x - \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor$. 
To make it more  formal though you would show that the string $G^{n-1}BG^{n-1}B\ldots$ has $x - \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor$ girls ($G^{n - 1}$ means $n - 1$ concatenated girls).

However there could be a better construction!
To prove equality, you need to argue that nothing is better, i.e. $M \leq x - \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor$.

But that should be easy to show.  Take a string $X$ with maximum girls.
Split it into the substrings 
$$X[1..n], X[n + 1..2n], X[2n + 1..3n], \ldots, X[(\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor - 1)n + 1 .. \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor n]$$

That last substring must exist since $\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor n \leq x$.
Now each of these substrings must contain at least one boy.  How many substrings are there ?

As for the relationship with grah theory, sorry I really don't see any.